# .NET GridView update won't send a UserID to the SQL Query

Tags: .net, sql, gridview, sqldatasource

I am at the moment trying to learn how to use basic grid view controls to display my data.

To start with I have tried to do everything through the aspx page to try and keep things simpler for myself.

Everything is working great so far, but I am having a problem with using an update query.

My desired result is just a simple 2 column table, which will display a users name, and then an edit button.

The problem is, that if I don't include the user ID in the columns the query does not update anything.

This is my SqlDataSource code:

```xml
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="sqlDataSource"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT UserID, Name FROM tblUsers;"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE tblUsers SET Name = @Name WHERE UserID = @UserID">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is my GridView:

```xml
<asp:GridView
    ID="Clients"
    DataSourceID="sqlDataSource"
    runat="server"
    AllowPaging="true"
    AllowSorting="true"
    PageSize="25"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="UserID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Users Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Edit" ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I go to the page and click edit, the Name field changes to a text box, and I can choose either update or cancel as expected.

But with the code above, when I click update it just displays the normal table again, with no changes to the data because SQL just isn't getting any UserID.

However if I add `<asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="Users ID" SortExpression="UserID" />` to the `<Columns>`, it works.

Is there any way for me to make this work without having to add the UserID column to the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the OldValuesParameterFormatString:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="sqlDataSource"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    SelectCommand="SELECT UserID, Name FROM tblUsers;"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE tblUsers SET Name = @Name WHERE UserID = @original_UserID">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_UserID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the column and set `Visible` to `False`.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" Visible="False" />
```

Comment: I just tried that, and unfortunately it doesn't work. Thank you for your time though!